# django can't pass dictdata into javascript variable

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django

I need to use django + angularjs for listing data with a powerful filter from angular.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('test',[ ]);
$scope.companies = data;
app.controller("TestList", function($scope) {
$scope.listData = data;
}
var data = ["{{dat}}"];
app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});
```

{{dat}} is a data which sent from django back-end
its couldn't shown.

I use a dictfetchall function to fetch data into a dictdata

```
def dictfetchall(cursor):
"Return all rows from a cursor as a dict"
columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
return [
    dict(zip(columns, row))
    for row in cursor.fetchall()
]
dat = dictfetchall(datCursor)
dictData['dat'] = dat
```

if I list data in a django form like

```
{% for list in dat %}
{{list.name}}
{% endif %}
```

its work, but I need to listing data parse in javascript format like this

```
var dataList = {{dat}};
```

its shouldn't work

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Django template engine's main purpose is to take collections of data and convert them into HTML. I may be wrong, but I do not recall any builtin tags or filters in the template engine that allow for automatic expansion of python lists/dicts to JSON string values. Generally the template language revolves around iterating over collections and converting their values into properly formatted and escaped string representations.

In this case, the most expedient solution for you is to make **dat** a string containing the JSON text you wish to substitute into the template.

Somewhere at the time of the file:

```
import json
```

Then change the line:

```
dictData['dat'] = dat
```

To:

```
dictData['dat'] = json.dumps(dat)
```

In which case the string variable substitution will provide the text json representation and the html should render correctly.